# Limit of functions

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I need to give a counterexample to the following statement:

> If $ \lim_{x \to 0} \left( \frac {f(x)}{g(x)} \right) = 1 $, then $ \lim_{x \to 0} \left( f(x) - g(x) \right) = 0 $.

The problem is I think this statement is correct for any functions because:

$$ \lim \left( \frac {f(x)}{g(x)} \right) = \dfrac {\lim \left( f(x) \right)}{\lim \left( g(x) \right)}, $$ so if it equals $1$< then both functions have the same limit so, if we subtract them, the limit is $0$.

I tried to find a counterexample for hours! And found nothing. Thanks for the help.

Comment: $f(x) = \dfrac{x+1}{x^2}$, $g(x) = \dfrac1{x^2}$.

Comment: Try to think it through: if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both really, really, big for $x$ near $0$, it is possible for their quotient to be close to $1$ and their difference to be large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting njguliyev's comment to an answer, consider: $$ \begin {eqnarray*} f(x) &=& \dfrac {x+1}{x^2}, \\ g(x) &=& \dfrac {1}{x^2}. \end {eqnarray*} $$